# Write Conflict between two transactions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, nosql

I am a noob in DBMS. I am developing a project which has multiple readers and writers.

Here are the steps of the project.

1. User Logins
2. Makes changes
3. Then clicks submit
4. Admins review the changes and merges with the main DB.

So, I thought let's use a transaction for each user when they login to my project. Because the transaction takes a snapshot and commits data if all the queries are executed without any error.

If two users want to write in the same row then the transaction throws an error that is required for the project.

Now my question is if such an error occurs then I want only that query to fail I still want the transaction to continue if it has no error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should show some code you have tried for these steps mentioned

Comment: @Mannoj Thank you. But I am still in design.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the concept of a database transaction in a wrong way. Database transactions should be very short (sub-second) and **never** involve user interaction. The idea is to group statements that belong together so that either all of them succeed or all fail.

What you want to do is application logic and should be handled by the application. That doesn't mean that you cannot use the database. For example, your table could have a column that persists the status (entered by client, approved, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest what to do? There is a Project which has 100 users maximum. Users make changes to the local database. After they're done with their change the submit it to admin. If the admin approves then their local DB merged with the main DB. But now only one user can access the project at once there is a lock. Users wait for there chance. I want to break this lock I,e multiple readers and writers in the database. I want something like a transaction, to take a snapshot of DB and allow users to make a change. If approved then commit to the main DB. What should be done?

Comment: You need someone to help you design an application. That exceeds what can be done in a Questions 6 Answers forum. You should get a technical consultant.